# Modify builtin extern for closure compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm working with google's closure compiler and I encountered the following error when building:

```
path/to/file.js:...: WARNING - actual parameter 1 of Element.prototype.scrollIntoView does not match formal parameter
found   : {behavior: string, block: string}
required: (boolean|undefined)
    target.scrollIntoView({'block': 'start', 'behavior': 'smooth'});
                          ^
```

Obviously, here `target` is an `Element`.

Ok, so it looks like closure wants a boolean, but mdn seems to think that [an object is a perfectly fine argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).  MDN references https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrollintoview for it's definition which agrees (and the smooth scrolling actually works in Firefox).

It looks like Closure defines the extern in [`w3c_css.js`](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/04dd916be73f961f489906231cfb1a1ad0fd583a/externs/browser/w3c_css.js#L2121) which references http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrollintoview in a comment.  However, it looks like they don't even have the definition there correct since `w3.org` has 2 (optional) arguments in the signature and closure seems to only allow passing 1.

Smooth scrolling is a nice-to-have (and I'll likely replace this piece of code with a better cross-browser solution at some point), but in the meantime, how do I silence that warning?

Comment: This bug seems to be fixed in more recent versions of the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Permanent answer

Submit a pull request to the github project and fix it for everyone: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/externs/browser/w3c_css.js#L2125 - If you aren't comfortable doing that, I'll do it for you.

### Temporary answer

Define your own extern overwriting the signature:

```
/** @externs */

/**
 * @suppress {duplicate}
 * @param {(boolean|{behavior: string, block: string})=} opt_top
 * @see http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrollintoview
 */
Element.prototype.scrollIntoView = function(opt_top) {};
```

Comment: Ahh, `@suppress`!  I had tried doing exactly this but without the `@suppress` so I got a different error.  As far as submitting the Pull-Request, I'm happy to do it, but, it seems that the signature of that function isn't necessarily agreed upon.  Some linked sources are saying it's `function(opt_top, opt_scrollOptions) {}` others just `function(opt_top) {}`.  I'm not sure who is right.

Comment: The spec references only one argument - go with that. FireFox looks to be the only major browser supporting the options argument, so as long as it works there, you are fine.

Comment: Hmm ... Just getting to trying this out and it seems that the temporary fix isn't suppressing the warning.  I put it into a separate file and it's added to the build command via `--externs=fix_compiler.js`, but the compiler is still issuing the warning.

Comment: Just ran it locally and it compiled with no errors. I used `document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].scrollIntoView({'block': 'start', 'behavior': 'smooth'});` as my javascript input.

Comment: With that input, it seems that closure isn't smart enough to know that it's working with an element (and it works with and without the extern).  I modified with a cast to `/** @type {!Element} */(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]).scrollIntoView({{'block': 'start', 'behavior': 'smooth'});` and the warning reappears.

Comment: I've merged the commit. You'll have to wait a couple of weeks for the next release, or build the compiler yourself from the source.

Comment: I'm adding an issue to the project regarding the inability to redefine an extern definition.